Turkey visit visa for 15 days duration instead of standard 30 days stay?
I got turkey visit visa which says the max stay for 15 days while the website says min 30 days visa is granted. I understand that I need to stay for 7 days in Turkey only which I mentioned in my application but does that mean even standard visa duration can be shortened individually?

Note: standard may be misleading. It may depends on your passport (so on reciprocity and quality of relation between the two countries, or also on the average abuse rate from citizens of your country), your age, your finances, etc. All facts you do not list in your question (and for most of them we cannot know exactly the internal rules).

Most likely, yes. Countries can limit the duration of a visa if eg the applicant meets the relevant eligibility rules but the IO decides the ‘standard’ length is not warranted (for reasons mentioned in @Giacomo Catenazzi’s comment), or their passport or visa permitting entry to another country will expire before a given date.

Thanks for useful input. Yeah I had mentioned in my application that I will stay 7 days in Istanbul and then will fly onwards to another country.
